# DateTime to Date without TimeStamp

Tags: c#

var date = (from rec in dcBusinessAccountingContext.WorkOrdersReportSP_Result  select rec.Date);

Here "var date" will have all the Dates from

"dcBusinessAccountingContext.WorkOrdersReportSP_Result" with time stamp, that var date i want

convert to Date without time stamp

ex: var date have "2013-05-20 11:52:51 AM" i want "2013-05-20"

How to convert this var date to only Date

thanks
prashanth

Comment: date.Date will do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Going on the basis `date` is a `DateTime` and not a `string`

```
var dateOnly = date.Date;
```

Or if you want just the date from the query

```
var date = from rec in dcBusinessAccountingContext.MaterialActivityReportSP_Results
           select rec.Trx_Date.Date;
```

Comment: If `date` is a sequence all of whose elements are to be affected, the first line shall read `var dateOnly = date.Select(d => d.Date);` of course.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yep that's why I just said for clarity *"Going on the basis `date` is a `DateTime`"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of DateTime object to get only date part.

```
var datePart = from rec in dcBusinessAccountingContext.MaterialActivityReportSP_Results
                select rec.Trx_Date.Date;
```

Comment: I assume this wouldn't compile as `(...)` would return an `IQueryable` so you couldn't just access `Date`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var date = (from rec in dcBusinessAccountingContext.MaterialActivityReportSP_Results select rec.Trx_Date.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: it is giving does not contain a definition for ToShortDateString